# Java button that selects three strings at random from three arrays onClick

Tags: java, android, button

I have three string arrays with about 40 words each. I need a button that will:

- select one string at random from each array
- display each string in their corresponding textView boxes
- and will not repeat a previous selection during the run.

I don't have any code samples, but I'm lost on where to look to figure it out or how to create the method and classes I need.

Comment: tv1.setText(myArray1[Math.random()*myArray1.length]); you should try to ask one thing at time, problem with the button click, with the arrays, with the textviews...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
// Assuming you have textViews declared and the arrays
int index = Math.random()*array1.length();
textView1.setText(array1[index]);
index = Math.random()*array2.length();
textView2.setText(array2[index]);
index = Math.random()*array3.length();
textView3.setText(array3[index]);
```

Put this code where you want to do that